# sp_blitzindex output

Tags: sp-blitzindex

I have latest version of `sp_blitzindex`.  Would like to store results in table. Runs no output, anyone doing this already?

Running with parameters below:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzIndex @databasename = 'ngprod',
    @OutputDatabaseName = 'dbaadmin',
    @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo',
    @OutputTableName ='BlitzIndexStats'
```

Table structure is below:

```
USE [DBAAdmin]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BlitzIndexStats]    Script Date: 6/7/2017 9:08:21 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlitzIndexStats](
    [Priority] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Finding] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [Details] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [Definition] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [SecretColumns] [varchar](512) NULL,
    [Usage] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Size] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CaptureDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlitzIndexStats] ADD  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [CaptureDate]
GO
```

Comment: I would update sp_BlitzIndex to insert the data into your custom table. You should be able to add an INSERT INTO right after the /*Return results.*/ comment using the same select block immediately after the comment-- which returns the results.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest sp_BlitzIndex and in the comments in the SP i found this:

> - The @OutputDatabaseName parameters are not functional yet. To check the    status of this enhancement request, visit:
>     https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/221

So you are not able to use that parameter.

Comment: Ok dumb question does the output to a table work (store results in database that the sp is being run against?

Comment: That should work. I haven't tried it but looking at the code it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get output saved to a table using sp_BlitzCache v5.6 but only with @mode=2.

Inside the proc I can see that its @Version = '5.6' and @VersionDate = '20170801' which as of this writing was yesterday.  I had a version that was probably a month old or so and @Mode=2 was not working so this appears to be a recent fix.

My command:

```
  exec sp_blitzindex @mode=2, @OutputDatabaseName=N'OUTPUT_DB', @OutputSchemaName=N'dbo', @OutputTableName=N'BLITZINDEX', @DatabaseName= N'TARGET_DB';
```